# laravel blade @include not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade, php-include

I am trying to include files in my homepage using blade syntax :-

```
@foreach($data as $articles)
    @include(app_path().$articles->path)
    <br />
@endforeach
```

This is not working.

The error says :-

```
View [/var/www/blogproject/project/app/pages/articles/first-post.php] not found
```

I even tried including just the first page :-

```
@include(app_path().'/pages/articles/first-post.php')
```

But the normal php include is working fine :-

```
<?php include(app_path().'/pages/articles/first-post.php'); ?>
```

Please help

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That's because that file is not in the **app/views** directory. When you call `@include('filename')`, Blade automatically looks for any file with that name, inside the **apps/views** directory. Also, you're not supposed to write the file extension, as Blade automatically looks for files with `.blade.php` and `.php` extensions.

If you want to use files from other directories on the `@include` tag, add the directory to the paths array, on **app/config/view.php**. In your case, it'd be something like this:

**app/config/view.php**

```
<?php

    // ...

    'paths' => array(
        __DIR__.'/../views',
        __DIR__.'/../pages'
    );
```

Then, you'd call it on blade like so:

```
@include('articles/first-post')
```

Comment: after i add __DIR__.'/../pages' do i need to run any comman in the terminal - I did this but after refreshing it says View [articles/first-post.php] not found

Comment: ya, without .php its working in both cases - but y is tat, is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Well, Blade's `@include` is meant for `.blade.php` and `.php` files only. So they made it so you don't actually need to write the extension and then made a dot notation possible. Like, `articles/first-post' is exactly the same as 'articles.first-post'. So, yes, I guess not writing the extension is the right way to go.

Comment: any idea how to put in the foreach loop, I am having troble ther also. @include($articles->path) does not seem to work

Comment: Try `@include(preg_replace('(path/|\.php)', '', $article->path))`

Comment: @rmobis Can't thank you enough about the "Dont add the extension in the include". No wonder my @include('next.blade.php') wasn't working....I was intuitively adding the extension like in php includes...

Comment: Might be worth adding if you're on a new version of Laravel (5+) you need to write @include('articles.first-post') and not @include('articles/first-post')